# What SwiftUI Component is used to implement the New Reminder form in the Reminders app?

Tags: swiftui

I've been learning SwiftUI (and loving it), but I'm struggling to find what built-in component is being used for this particular UI (in the picture I've uploaded). This particular form pops up from the bottom (animated) and can be swiped down to dismiss.

[image: AddReminderUi]

In particular, what's the UI element used to build this "overlay card". The `TextField` and form layout is familiar to me, but I cannot seem to find it which SwiftUI component to wrap them in based on my perusal of the docs.

Comment: Are you looking for [`sheet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitview/sheet(ispresented:ondismiss:content:))?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Although, that link is broken for me. [This one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(ispresented:ondismiss:content:)) works for me though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is [`sheet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(ispresented:ondismiss:content:)), although credit goes to Sweeper.